# Blacklist cross-domain policy file

Tags: actionscript-3, crossdomain.xml

Is it possible with a cross-domain policy file for use with Flash/AS3 to specify a blacklist? i.e. allow all URLs except the ones listed? So far I have only used it with whitelisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf) appears to only support whitelisting; all settings are of the form "allow-access-from", not "deny-access-from".